# Type D Schengen Visa Technicalities Issues 3rd Countries

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration

I have read several threads regarding type D visas but that doesn't seem to answer my seemingly specific question.

I am working in the Philippines for an international company and I have been granted a 1 year, **multiple entry German Type D Visa with working permit valid until Feb 10, 2019** to perform work with one of our clients.

**I have already been in Germany**, finished my assignment for the time being and now I am **back to the Philippines**. Therefore I used the visa it was intended for the first time.

Currently I've been invited by my close friends to visit them **(social visit) in Norway from Dec 15, 2018 to Feb 1, 2019**. It means that I'm planning to travel to Norway while my German Type D Visa is still valid. I am willing to apply for a Norwegian Short Stay Visa however it might be all for naught as I still have a valid Type D visa.

I would like to know your inputs if it's possible to travel to Norway (Schengen area) with probable point of entry via Amsterdam. using a valid, multiple entry German Type D visa without applying for a Norwegian Short Stay Visa? if so, what kind of critical supplemental documents I might need?

I'm quite afraid that I might miss some technicalities and might cause some issues in the border control.

Additional to that, is the 90/180 still counts at this point? previous threads mentioned this quite a lot but I read [[REGULATION (EU) 2016/399]](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0399&qid=1541765778750&from=EN)

> Article 6
>   Entry conditions for third-country nationals
>
> 1. For intended stays on the territory of the Member States of a duration of no more than 90 days in any 180-day
>      period, which entails considering the 180-day period preceding each day of stay, the entry conditions for third-country
>      nationals shall be the following:
>      (a) they are in possession of a valid travel document entitling the holder to cross the border satisfying the following
>      criteria:
>      (i) its validity shall extend at least three months after the intended date of departure from the territory of the Member
>      States. In a justified case of emergency, this obligation may be waived;
>      (ii) it shall have been issued within the previous 10 years;
>      (b) they are in possession of a valid visa, if required pursuant to Council Regulation (EC) No 539/2001 (1), **except where
>      they hold a valid residence permit or a valid long-stay visa;**
> 2. For the purposes of implementing paragraph 1, the date of entry shall be considered as the first day of stay on the
>      territory of the Member States and the date of exit shall be considered as the last day of stay on the territory of the
>      Member States. **Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be taken into account in
>      the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member States.**

Help or inputs regarding this matter are appreciated. *Also I attached my visa details for referrence*

[Visa and work permit image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq9EA.jpg)

Comment: @Giorgio the other question appears not to concern a type-D visa.

Comment: John, are you eligible for visa-free travel as a short-term visitor?

Comment: @phoog no, I need visa as a short-term visitor. I'm asking for future reference if ever I apply for Short-Stay Visa